# Data from another class cannot be put to a datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop

Good day. I have passed a data variable from one class to another to put into a datagridview in the main form. I put some message boxes in each case to know that it accesses the said function and that the data is clearly passed. But when I run the program. The table doesn't put the data inside it.

Here is the code when I pass the data

```
if (txtCode1.ElementAt(intCtr + 1).Equals(val4)) {
   MessageBox.Show("Lol");
   Compilourdes_GUI cmp = new Compilourdes_GUI();
   cmp.AddtotblLexeme(val2, val2);
   break;
}
```

And here is the code of AddtotblLexeme

```
public void AddtotblLexeme(string lexeme, string token) {
   MessageBox.Show(lexeme+" "+token);
   tblLexeme.Rows.Add(lexeme , token); //adding tokens and lexeme to the table
}
```

Code where I made the DataTable

```
private void Start()
{
    tbl1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    tbl1.DataSource = null;
    tbl1.Rows.Clear();

    InitTable();

    string txtCode1 = txtCode.Text;
    LexicalAnalyzer lex = new LexicalAnalyzer(txtCode1);
    lex.StartLex();
    tbl1.DataSource = tblLexeme;
}

public void InitTable()
{
    tblLexeme = new DataTable();
    tblLexeme.Columns.Add("Lexeme", typeof(string));
    tblLexeme.Columns.Add("Token", typeof(string));
}

DataTable tblLexeme = new DataTable();
```

Here is the image of the output [image: the "TEST" word/s should be inside the table]. the "TEST" word/s should be inside the table, but as you can see, it didn't get put in.

Comment: You don't show the code for this, but I presume tblLexeme is the DataSource for the DataGridView?

Comment: `Program.compForm` - what is this?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock yes. 

Sinatr, I initialized compForm as a new instance of the GUI form.

Comment: In your screen shot you show columns Lexeme and Token.  Are these bound columns?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I don't get what you mean.

Comment: The Column headers appear in the DataGridView - how did they get there?

Comment: I used the Add Column dialog on the Designer.

Comment: Do you call Start before AddtotblLexeme?

Comment: Yes I did call it.

Comment: I've emailed you a fix

Comment: Thank you so much Sir Jonathan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I understand your problem.  If you added the columns directly in the designer, my guess is that you added unbound columns.  If so, then the DataGridView cannot match up the row you are adding to the rows in the table.  To fix this, delete the columns from the DatagridView.  Then make sure that your DataGridView has property AutoGenerateColumns = true, before setting DataSource = tblLexeme.  Now two things happen automatically: firstly the DataGridView picks up the columns from your DataTable; and secondly, when adding a new row to the DataTable, it should show automatically in the DataGridView.

In AddtotblLexeme, for testing purposes, can you please add, in place of your Rows.Add():

```
DataRow nR = tblLexeme.NewRow();
nR[0] = lexeme;
nR[1] = token;
tblLexeme.Rows.Add(nR);
```

Then in debugger check that nR does have an ItemArray with 2 columns.

Comment: I got this error: "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."

Comment: @schwall Please edit your question and show code where you create the DataTable

Comment: It said that it cannot find column 0.

Comment: Then either Start has NOT been called, or the DataTable has been re-created.  I really need to see the full code to determine which.  If you don't want to post it here, you could email me.

Comment: Ok sir. What parts of the code do you need? I could also email you instead.

Comment: It will be quickest if you zip your solution and email to jwillcock19@gmail.com

Comment: I have emailed you sir. Please check your email